# Reshape Pandas DataFrame to a Series with columns prefixed with indices

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a Pandas DataFrame like this one:

```
      A    B
idx1  1    3
idx2  2    4
```

Is there a pandas function that converts this table to something like this?

```
A_idx1  A_idx2 B_idx1 B_idx
1       2      3      4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), convert to DataFrame and transpose, last join `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df1 = df.unstack().to_frame().T
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df1)
   A_idx1  A_idx2  B_idx1  B_idx2
0       1       2       3       4
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved my question.